# mypy: Cannot infer type argument 1 of "map"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, mypy, type-annotation

When trying to check the following code using mypy:

```
import itertools
from typing import Sequence, Union, List
        
DigitsSequence = Union[str, Sequence[Union[str, int]]]


def normalize_input(digits: DigitsSequence) -> List[str]:
    try:
        new_digits = list(map(str, digits))  # <- Line 17
        if not all(map(str.isdecimal, new_digits)):
            raise TypeError
    except TypeError:
        print("Digits must be an iterable containing strings.")
        return []
    return new_digits
```

mypy throws the following errors:

> calculate.py:17: error: Cannot infer type argument 1 of "map"

Why does this error occur? How can I fix it?

Thanks :)

**Edit:** It was actually a [bug](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3682) in mypy, and it's fixed now.

Comment: Considering [`str` is basically `Sequence[str]`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/builtins.pyi#L232), you could rewrite `Union[str, Sequence[Union[str, int]]]` to `Sequence[Union[str, int]]` and then the error goes away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you may already know, [mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy) depends on [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed) to stub the classes and functions in Python's standard library. I believe your issue this has to do with typeshed's [stubbing of `map`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/2d96eecd3008272ea656b031c9fba81f49832580/stdlib/3/builtins.pyi#L797):

```
@overload
def map(func: Callable[[_T1], _S], iter1: Iterable[_T1]) -> Iterator[_S]: ...
```

And that the current state of mypy is such that its type inference is not unbounded. (The project also has [over 600 open issues.](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues))

I believe your problem may be related to [issue #1855](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1855). I believe this to be the case because `DigitsSequence = str` and `DigitsSequence = Sequence[int]` both work whereas `DigitsSequence = Union[str, Sequence[int]]` does not.

Some workarounds:

1. Use a lambda expression instead:

   ```
   new_digits = list(map(lambda s: str(s), digits))
   ```
2. Re-cast to a new variable:

   ```
   any_digits = digits # type: Any
   new_digits = list(map(str, any_digits))
   ```
3. Ask mypy to ignore the line:

   ```
   new_digits = list(map(str, digits)) # type: ignore
   ```